# IE11 browser shape overflows SVG element

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg

I'm working on an SVG and trying to create half circle but the IE11 browser creates complete circle instead.

My code is like this:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 80 40" class="gauge">
  <circle 
    cx="40"
    cy="40"
    r="37"
    fill="transparent"
    stroke="#d2d3d4"
    stroke-width="6"></circle>
</svg>
```

How can I render half circle in IE11?
It is working fine on other browsers. Please find the below image for more reference.

**On IE11 :**

[image: Image for IE11 browser]

**On Chrome :**

[image: Image for chrome]

Comment: overflow="hidden" on the <svg> element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix would be to add `overflow:hidden;` on the svg like so :

```css
svg {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 80 40" class="gauge">
  <circle 
    cx="40" 
    cy="40" 
    r="37" 
    fill="transparent" 
    stroke="#d2d3d4" 
    stroke-width="6"></circle>
</svg>
```

Depending on your use case, a "cleaner" solution would be to build your half circle with a path and the [arc command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Arcs) :

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 80 40" class="gauge">
  <path d="M3 40 A37 37 0 0 1 77 40"
    fill="transparent" 
    stroke="#d2d3d4" 
    stroke-width="6" />
</svg>
```

This way you are sure nothing overflows the svg element.